# Getting a value where 3 other values (different column) find that particular value

Tags: sql, teradata

What I'm looking to do is find a date and trans_id where item_nbr = 1, 2, and 3 (in no particular order).  All 3 items must be found with the same trans_id.

So table looks like this:

```
trans_id, trans_date, item_nbr, item, price
```

Table looks like:

```
trans_id--trans_date--item_nbr--item--price    
1234--1/1/2015--1--item1--1.00   
1234--1/1/2015--3--item3--3.00    
1234--1/1/2015--2--item2--2.00    
4321--1/1/2015--2--item2--2.00
```

Results should be:

```
1/1/2015--1234
```

The query should only return the date and trans_id, though.

So this is what I have so far, but I know it's incorrect since it pulls back all the date/trans_id that include items 1, 2 and/or 3, not 1,2,3 in the same date and trans_id.

```
select date, trans_id
from table1
where item in ('item1', 'item2', 'item3')
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is something like this:

```
select date, trans_id
from table1
where item in ('item1', 'item2', 'item3')
group by date, trans_id
```

let me know if that works!

edit: got the wrong column my mistake!

Comment: I knew what you meant.  :)  Got zero results.  I know for a fact that items 1,2,3 were all sold in the same transaction a handful of times.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are close.  Just use `group by` and `having`:

```
select date, trans_id
from table1
where item in ('item1', 'item2', 'item3')
group by date, trans_id
having count(distinct item) = 3;
```

EDIT:

If `having count(distinct item) = 3` returns no results, then you have no cases where all three items are in the same transaction on the same date.

You might consider removing the `date` from the `select` and `group by`.  It seems awkward there.  I only left it in because it is in the query in your question.

Comment: I get zero results when using 'distinct' within the having statement.  When I removed 'distinct', I continue to get all results - not just records where all 3 items exist.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

```
select date, trans_id
from table1
where item in ('item1', 'item2', 'item3')
group by 1,2
having count(*) = 3
```

If `item` is not unique you must use

```
having count(distinct item) = 3
```

Comment: I get zero results when using 'distinct' within the having statement. When I removed 'distinct', I continue to get all results - not just records where all 3 items exist. Any thoughts?

Comment: @DJDJ23: You might change the `date` to `MIN(date)` and remove it from `GROUP BY` to check if it's actually the same date.

Answer (score 0):

You can count distinct values

```
;WITH cte (trans_id) AS (
     SELECT trans_id
     FROM table1 
     Group By trans_id 
     Having Count(distinct item_nbr) = (Select Count(Distinct item_nbr) from table1))

Select DISTINCT trans_id, trans_date 
From table1 
Where trans_id IN (
Select trans_id from  cte)
```

OR

```
Select DISTINCT trans_id, trans_date 
    From table1 
    Where trans_id IN (
    SELECT trans_id
         FROM table1 
         Group By trans_id 
         Having Count(distinct item_nbr) = (Select Count(Distinct item_nbr) from table1))
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the solution.  Not sure if it's the most efficient, but I decided to create a volatile table for each item, then query the 3 volatile tables based on date,trans_id and few other fields not mentioned in my example.

Thanks all for the help!